# Как остановить основной цикл что бы выполнилась функция в потоке

Tags: python, многопоточность

Я пытался с помощью глобальной переменной расставить приоритеты выполнения, но это срабатывает через раз, мне нужно гарантированно остановить основной цикл что бы выполнилась функция из потока.

```
def stalking():
    while True:
        a = get_cord('tan.jpg', conf=0.8)
        if a == None:
            a = get_cord('tan.jpg', conf=0.7)
        if a != None:
            something(False)#делает переменную value данным значением  
            #Далее основной код но в нем ничего особенного  
thr = threading.Thread(target=stalking)
thr.start()
while True:
    if value:
        complete_mission()#Довольно длинные действия которые и необходимо прервать
```

Comment: В функции переменная `value` должна быть описана как `global`. Но лучше какие-то примитивы синхронизации использовать специальные.

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема, вам нужно прервать во время выполнения `complete_mission`? Или между выполнениями? Это важно, т.к. в питоне нет способа прервать выполнение произвольной функции (когда я говорю "произвольной", то имею ввиду, что эту функцию писали не вы или писали вы но не полностью, т.е. если она внутри вызывает другие, например, библиотечные функции). Чтоб остановить надежно, нужно чтоб функция вела себя "правильно", и была готова остановиться. Т.е. регулярно проверяла "а не пробуют ли меня остановить". Если проблема именно в реализации регулярной проверки, то нужно более четко

Comment: показать как определена `value`, как ее устанавливаете. Тут важны подробности именно этого. Что-то делаете не так, если не работает, но что - из вопроса не ясно. Ну и нужно понимать, что время реакции, т.е. между запросом на остановку и остановкой, будет равно периодичности проверки флага. Если периодичность большая, то и задержка будут такая же.